# How to get the word which exactly match with word in file in python

Tags: python

```
infile = open('file.txt', 'r')
string = infile.read()

def extract_edu(string):
    with open('totaleducation.txt', 'r') as totaledu:
        edu_set=[]
        for edu in totaledu:
            if edu in string:
                print(edu)
                edu_set.append(edu)
    return edu_set
```

I want to extract the word from string which match in totaleducation file.  If return's correctly if it is in one word like BCA but when i extract like MCA (Master of Computer Application) it ignore this line.

```
String is just a document text file like ACADEMICS:

Year
Degree
Institute/College
University
CGPA/Percentage
2016
MSc (Computer-Science)
South Asian University
South Asian University
6.6/9
2012
BCA
Ignou, Patna
IGNOU
65
2009
Class XII(Science)
BSSRPP Inter College Deoria
BHSIE
61
2006
Class X
Buxar High School
BSEB
67.8
, and totaleducation.txt is just like 
MSc
BCA
MCA
Master's of Science
```

.

Comment: Perhaps you want the comparison the other way around? `if string in edu:`

Comment: No, it didn't work, it returns [ ]

Comment: Edit your question to include the value of `string` that you're passing into the function, and a sample line in the input file that you would expect to be a match.

Comment: your question is not clear, put more contents like code and sample input and file content

Comment: @johnII I edit it

Comment: @JayPratapPandey I believe the error is due to you calling the function as `extract_edu(BCA)`. You should either fix the code to compare `if str(string) in edu` (which is the better way) or call `extract_edu("BCA")`.

Comment: include complete error trace-back

Comment: @Gahan It didn't get error, it didn't return all output.

Comment: then write what you are getting, what you want.. and a sample of text file

Comment: @JayPratapPandey I am hoping you are not asking Python what `edu_set` is, because it is always going to be `[]`. Are you calling `extract_edu("BCA")` or `extract_edu(BCA)`?

Comment: in String like: BCA MCA (Master of computer Application) MSc( Master of Science), in total education file like MCA BCA MSc I want to all matching word but it return only BCA except BCA, MCA, MSc

Comment: please put something that will explain what you want, what the input is, what is the file content

e.g. given this file content and this "string" as input, i want to do this when this is the case etc etc

Comment: @JayPratapPandey Please edit your question with some sample lines and describe what the desired behavior from those lines are.

Comment: string is a text file? you mean the input is a text file?

Comment: @johnII, yes string is text file and it is mine input and i want to return the all word which match in totaleducation datasets

Comment: then specify it on your question, first you shoudn't use "string" if you meant "file" that's one of the confusion

Comment: @JayPratapPandey it is still very unclear. Let's clarify this one at least: After you define this function, how are you calling it? Are you running `extract_edu("BCA")` or `extract_edu("BCA MCA (Master of computer Application) MSc( Master of Science)")` or `extract_edu("string.txt")` or something else? How exactly are you using that function?

Comment: @FatihAkici In extract_edu(string), it is not string it is a text file like resume. and I want to return all the matching word in totaleducation.

Comment: @JayPratapPandey So you are trying to find all matching words in two separate txt files?

Comment: @FatihAkici Yes one file is txt file and another file may be txt or csv file

Comment: @JayPratapPandey You know this is some very essential information, right? :) Please include this clarification in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long discussions, we clarified that the question is:

I have one text file called `totaleducation.txt`, and another text/csv file called `sample.txt`; and I want to find every word in `totaleducation.txt` that also exists in `sample.txt`.

So for this, you should read `totaleducation.txt` line-by-line, and check if each of those lines exist in any line of `sample.txt`.

```
def match():
    words = []
    with open('totaleducation.txt', 'r') as f1:
        for edu in f1:
            with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f2:
                for string in f2:
                    if edu.strip('\n') in string.strip('\n'):
                        words.append(edu.strip('\n'))
    return words
```

Calling `match()` will give you all of the words of `totaleducation.txt` that also exist in any line of `sample.txt`.

Pay attention to the `.strip('\n')`. Say in file1 you have 'MSc' and in file2 you have 'MSc (Computer-Science)'. It will fail to verify that 'MSc' is in 'MSc (Computer-Science)' if you omit the `.strip('\n')`; because actually the two lines are 'MSc\n' and 'MSc (Computer-Science)\n', and the first one is not in the second.

Second way of doing the same thing -if your files are not too big to cause memory issues-:

```
education = []
with open('totaleducation.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        education.append(line.strip('\n'))

sample = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        sample.append(line.strip('\n'))

match = [e for e in education for s in sample if e in s]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it didn't get correct result

Comment: @JayPratapPandey Let's make it work. Let's stick with the second way that I mention. Can you run it and give me a few (like 10) elements of education and sample?